# Meaning of "handsome as hell"

Tags: phrase-meaning

What does **handsome as hell** means? I heard it in [Wildest Dreams](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/taylorswift/wildestdreams.html) sung by **Taylor Swift**. The wording of the song goes like:

> He's so tall and handsome as hell.
>   He's so bad but he does it so well

Is this phrase good to use?

Comment: "as hell" is an expletive used for emphasis.  Expletives are fungible.  You could say "Handsome as all get-out".  Even "handsome as shit."  But you do not use such phrases in formal contexts. Social etiquette dictates that they are for use among friends and peers in casual contexts.

Comment: @TRomano You can write is as answer. I will vote it up.

Answer (score 3):

The basic construction *as [adjective] as [expletive]* essentially extends more literal / transparently metaphorical usages such as *as good as gold, as hard as nails, as nice as pie*.

Additional to OP's cited ***hell*** usage there's the slightly more euphemistic...

> [*He's as mad as **heck***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22mad%20as%20heck%22)
>    ...and the more explicitly coarse...
>    [*He's angry as **fuck***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22angry%20as%20fuck%22)
>    [*(It was as) dark as **buggery***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22dark%20as%20buggery%22) (this one's far from common, particularly in AmE)

But note that not many "expletives" can be used in this way. Despite what the prudes say, people who swear a lot don't necessarily do this because they have limited command of the language. The "rules" of swearing are often *extremely* precise - unsurprisingly, since one of its more important functions is to easily distinguish ["in-group" from "out-group"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ingroups_and_outgroups) speakers.

In the coarser versions, there's usually no specific *semantic* content to the particular expletive. They're all just used to convey emphasis (and/or prosody/rhyme in OP's example).

If anyone can suggest any other expletives that can be used in this pattern, please add a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your particular example is a truncated [simile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simile) combined with a bit of [alliteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alliteration). The full phrase would be "he is as handsome as hell is hot". It's reinforced by the fact that "hot" alone is used to refer to a physically attractive person.

The rest of the song lyric plays with it even further, by tying in the idea that "Hell" is were sinners go, but sins can be fun.

It's perfectly fine to use in casual language. However, "hell" is considered profanity by some, so it is not always appropriate.

Comment: I *don't* agree that the usage is a shortening of *as handsome as hell is hot*. I'm not necessarily saying it's a euphemistic version of [*as handsome as **fuck***](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22as+handsome+as+fuck%22), but it's in that general area.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think your logic is backwards. Tell me then, how handsome fuck is. Or to use TRomano's comment, tell me how handsome shit is. Both of them are substituting a different profanity for "hell", but without the original, logical derivation, are meaningless out of context.

Comment: How handsome *fuck* is is a meaningless question. You might as well ask [*How **bored** is **fuck**?*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22as+bored+as+fuck%22)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes; that's exactly the point I'm making: The complete simile using using "hell" and "hot" makes logical sense. The alternative profanity substitutions do not make sense, unless you reference them as different levels of vulgarity tied to the one profanity that does make sense.

Comment: Per my own answer, the idiomatic *as [adjective] as [expletive]* is well-established, and the specific expletives *hell, heck* certainly *don't* derive from some "original" literal usage based on Hell being hot. I admire your "sensitivity" in picking up on a potential allusion to modern *hot = attractive*, but I seriously doubt that was a factor in the lyricist's mind at the time.

Comment: "[Something] as ......"  sets the listener up to expect a simile.  Throw a power word like "hell" or "fuck" in where the simile ought to be and the effect is to put strong emphasis on the [something].  I agree with @FumbleFingers that there is no inherent meaning, anymore than there is when the Smurfs drop "smurf" into their sentences.

Comment: @Adam: Granted there's no significant *semantic* content to the specific expletive in this construction. But it's still [syntactically?] constrained, in that very few expletives can validly be used. Nobody ever says, for example, *as stupid as bollocks*, even though stupid things / people are often dismissed as *a load of bollocks / bollock-brained*. And I suspect *sure as shit* only exists because of the alliteration - I never hear anything like *as stupid as shit* (and *as soft as shit(e)* is more "metaphor" than "emphasis").

Comment: @FumbleFingers I can't speak to the usage of "bollocks, as it doesn't get much use in the U.S., but ""stupid as shit?"  Sure - slightly less common than "dumb as shit," but still within the common vulgar lexicon.  "Stupid as shit/hell/fuck" are all used over here.  That car is as faster than shit. That guy is dumb as fuck.  It's cold as hell in here.  Those three intensifiers are used in ways that make no semantic sense _all the time._